# LocalStorage objects are not being rendered

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I'm trying to render localStorage items of the form (fields variable) to the localstorage and then getting them to render them on the loop. But the items are not getting rendered and only a comma is rendered. I can't seem to get around this error...

```
let myLibrary = [];

const addBook = (event) => {
  event.preventDefault()
    var fields = {
      title: document.getElementById("title").value,
      author: document.getElementById("author").value,
      pages: document.getElementById("pages").value,
      checkbox: document.getElementById("checkbox").value
    };


myLibrary.push(fields)

localStorage.setItem('books', JSON.stringify(myLibrary));
const data = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('books'))



document.getElementById('bookList').innerHTML = data.map(item => {
  `<div>
    <div>Title: ${item.title}</div>
    <div>Author: ${item.author}</div>
    <div>Pages: ${item.pages}</div>
  </div>`
})


}
```

Comment: Did you console data ? What are you gettibg in data var ?

Comment: ```[{…}]```

getting this. Don't know if you can read it and when you open it. It appears the object

```0:
author: "wdwdw"
checkbox: "on"
pages: "dwe"
title: "1234" ```

but the objects are not getting rendered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `map` function is returning an array, and without some sort of `toString` function on the elements in that array, I imagine it's giving you issues.

A different approach might be to simply use `forEach`, like this:

```js
const bookList = document.querySelector("#bookList");
data.forEach(item =>{
  bookList.innerHTML += /* your string here */
})
```

Or, perhaps better, create the actual DOM nodes you wish to append, and use that:

```js
const bookList = document.querySelector("#bookList");

bookList.append(...data.map(/* here, a function to create the actual DOM nodes rather than a string*/) );
```

That would work because you're spreading an array of DOM nodes as parameters to the append method: https://devdocs.io/dom/element/append